# How do I only serve the login page javascript instead of the whole app.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I have a Vue.js app wrapped in a Laravel application with authentication set up.
Regarding security, I don't want to serve the whole `app.js` in the request to the login page.
Technically any user (with or without ill intent) has access to all information written in the javascript code. For example route definitions and static text.

One way to prevent this would be to disconnect the login page from Vue.js and serve it as a blade file. This would work fine, but I'd prefer to stay in the Vue.js context.

Is there a way to only serve the "login page javascript" for the login page and load the rest after the user successfully logged into the application?

Comment: From Vue point of view, this can be done by adding separate login app, or using dynamic imports withing a single app. The problem is made-up for the most part because security through obscurity isn't a good strategy. *Technically any user (with or without ill intent) has access to all information written in the javascript code. For example route definitions and static text.* - that's correct, and this can happen any way because nothing is safe on client side. Double check what are your concerns regarding sensitive information that JS contains. If it really is then serve it through API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me tell you the thought I had when asking this question: I never give anyone the key to my house of course, but giving them "access" to all of my frontend code(Information) is like giving someone the address belonging to said key. Its generally safe to do so, but you still try to prevent mass distribution.

Comment: In general, I'm fine with having them know my address (or e.g. route definitions etc. in this case) but a colleage brought it up and I wanted to research more.

As the developer of this app, I really dont want to disconnect the login at all. I'm just looking for information.

So how would the frontend code not be save, if you needed to be authenticated to even load the Vue.js app?

Comment: *like giving someone the address belonging to said key* - this is what security through obscurity is. It's an acceptable extra measure of security but wrong way of thinking. Better focus the efforts on that an intruder knows the address one way or another, but can't use this information further. Client code just shouldn't contain anything that compromises the security in the first place. *if you needed to be authenticated to even load the Vue.js app?* - What you describe is corner case, it's ok for a paranoid project but not something that is common in modern API-powered web apps.

Comment: My primary concerns for this scenario is that dashboard app potentially exposes internal business processes. Any way, that's it, if you don't want main app to be available to the outside, create a separate gatekeeper app.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you for your thoughts!